# netsuite saved search value return

Tags: netsuite

This might be an easy question to answer, but I haven't been able to find it elsewhere.

I am creating a saved search that needs to return a list of customers that don't have a special value field checked in their address section. It's possible for them to have multiple addresses, with only one being checked. I don't want the saved search to display that customer if any of their addresses have been checked. Here is what I have, but its not working as expected:

```
New Saved Search -> criteria -> summary = 
Summary type = Sum
Field = Formula (Numeric)

Formula is as follows:
case when {address.custrecord_lu_stockist_address_eligible} = 'T' then 
1 else 0 end

FORMULA (NUMERIC) = less than

Value = 1

Thanks in advance for your help!
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say in what way your results differ from what you expect, however I know from experience that it's easy to miss this: when using a Summary criteria, you also have to specify a grouping within the results.

Go to the Results tab and enter Group as the Summary Type for Name (to group by customer).  If this returns the list of customers you're expecting you will of course need to add a Summary type to the other fields to make them show too.

I tested the criteria you show above (although on a different field) and it works perfectly when the results are grouped.